# pgfgetlastxy inside a scope

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the hack [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479101/93163) to draw an axis in a tikzpicture and "recreate" the coordinate system in a scope after leaving the axis environment (in order to be able to use `foreach` commands). However, it seems that `\pgfgetlastxy` returns the coordinates in the wrong coordinate system. Consider this example

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
    \coordinate (O) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \coordinate (X) at (axis cs:1,0);
    \coordinate (Y) at (axis cs:0,1);
  \end{axis}
  \begin{scope}[x={($(X)-(O)$)}, y={($(Y)-(O)$)}, shift={(O)}]
    \coordinate (A) at (0.5, 0.5);
    \path (A);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};
    \show\XCoord % Shows 97.49985pt
    \show\YCoord % Shows 80.99976pt
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I transform `(97.49985pt, 101.2497pt)` into the original `(0.5,0.5)`? Or better yet, is there a command that returns those coordinates?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170015/convert-from-physical-dimensions-to-axis-cs-coordinate-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your question is about PGF/TikZ, not `pgfplots`. The command `\pgfgetlastxy` returns numbers in `pt`. To get some number in `cm`, you can use

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dABcm}{\dAB*(1pt)/(1cm)}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!30] (-1,-1) grid (5,4);
\path
(0,0) coordinate (A) node[below left]{A}
(4,3) coordinate (B) node[above right]{B};

\path (A); \pgfgetlastxy{\xA}{\yA};
\path (B); \pgfgetlastxy{\xB}{\yB};

\pgfmathsetmacro{\dAB}{veclen(\xB-\xA,\yB-\yA)}
\draw (A)--(B) node[midway,above,sloped]{$\dAB$ pt};

\pgfmathsetmacro{\dABcm}{\dAB*(1pt)/(1cm)}
\path (A)--(B) node[midway,below,sloped]{$\dABcm$ cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You may want to control precision of numbers. To do that, set `precision` in \pgfkeys

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}
```

and write out with `\pgfmathprintnumber` as explained in Section 97 Number Printing in [pgfmanual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}
\draw[gray!30] (-1,-1) grid (5,4);
\path
(0,0) coordinate (A) node[below left]{A}
(4,3) coordinate (B) node[above right]{B};

\path (A); \pgfgetlastxy{\xA}{\yA};
\path (B); \pgfgetlastxy{\xB}{\yB};

\pgfmathsetmacro{\dAB}{veclen(\xB-\xA,\yB-\yA)}
\draw (A)--(B) node[midway,above,sloped]{$\pgfmathprintnumber{\dAB}$ pt};

\pgfmathsetmacro{\dABcm}{\dAB*(1pt)/(1cm)}
\path (A)--(B) node[midway,below,sloped]{$\pgfmathprintnumber{\dABcm}$ cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update** Note that if we use some explicit or implicit scaling, then all numbers (coordinates) are also be scaled with them same rate. For example,in the above code, use `[scale=1.5]` then printing the distance of AB will give `7.5 cm` instead `5 cm`. Unfortunately, `pgfplots` use [implicit scaling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125774/140722), that is, there are some scaling factor that users does not know; therefore, this solution can not be applied for `pgfplots`. My suggestion is using plain TikZ without any scaling option.

Comment: Thank you. In my MWE, I tried `\pgfmathsetmacro{\cmXCoord}{\XCoord*(1pt)/(1cm)}` but then I got the value `3.42673` instead of `0.5` that I specified. Is there a way to transform back into my input?

Comment: @Tohiko `pgfplots` use implicit scaling. Please see my update!